# VSTS not showing passing NUnit tests in results

Tags: unit-testing, powershell, nunit, azure-pipelines

I'm very new to powershell unit testing. I wrote my "hello world" tests below:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param()

Describe MyFailTest{
    Assert-Throws {
         throw "I do nothing interesting."
    } -MessagePattern "Not that message because I want a failure"
}

Describe MyPassTest{
    Assert-Throws {
        throw "I will pass"
    } -MessagePattern "I will pass"
}
```

And that looks like I would expect when run locally, the first one fails as the message pattern did not match, and the second test passes.

Now I'm trying to run the test as part of a CI/CD pipeline. I'm using "Pester Test Runner from Black Marble" task to kick off my .tests.ps1 files. In my NUnit output I can see it marked my tests as passing and failing as expected.

So now we get to the odd part. I used the publish results task in VSTS and I only ever see failed tests. Why am I not seeing passing tests as well? Seems odd it reports that 1/1 tests failed if I have a successful test run. I don't see any options to change that. I tried setting the Outcome filter to "All" in the tests tab. Any ideas?

Pertinent log sections:

```
Evaluating condition for step: 'Pester Test Runner'
Evaluating: succeeded()
Evaluating succeeded:
=> (Boolean) True
Expanded: True
Result: True
##[section]Starting: Pester Test Runner
==============================================================================
Task         : Pester Test Runner from Black Marble
Description  : Run Pester tests without the need to install Pester in with the PMModule folder or in the source repo (Using Pester 3.4.3 or 4.0.8)
Version      : 6.0.9
Author       : Richard Fennell
Help         : Version: 6.0.9. [More Information](https://github.com/rfennell/vNextBuild/wiki/Pester-Task/)
==============================================================================
Preparing task execution handler.
Executing the powershell script: d:\a\_tasks\Pester_31ef0033-64e3-4c55-b888-f446541474a6\6.0.9\Pester.ps1
PowerShellHandler.Execute - AddCommand(d:\a\_tasks\Pester_31ef0033-64e3-4c55-b888-f446541474a6\6.0.9\Pester.ps1)
PowerShellHandler.Execute - Add inputParameters
PowerShellHandler.Execute - AddParameter(scriptFolder=d:\a\1\s\Tasks\XXXXTWStaging\Tests\)
PowerShellHandler.Execute - AddParameter(resultsFile=d:\a\1\s\Test-Pester.XML)
PowerShellHandler.Execute - AddParameter(CodeCoverageOutputFile=)
PowerShellHandler.Execute - AddParameter(tag=)
PowerShellHandler.Execute - AddParameter(excludeTag=)
PowerShellHandler.Execute - AddParameter(pesterVersion=4.0.8)
PowerShellHandler.Execute - AddParameter(run32Bit=False)
PowerShellHandler.Execute - AddParameter(moduleFolder=)
PowerShellHandler.Execute - Invoke
Running in AMD64 PowerShell
Loading Pester module from [D:\a\_tasks\Pester_31ef0033-64e3-4c55-b888-f446541474a6\6.0.9\4.0.8]
Loading module from path 'D:\a\_tasks\Pester_31ef0033-64e3-4c55-b888-f446541474a6\6.0.9\4.0.8\Pester.psd1'.
Loading module from path 'D:\a\_tasks\Pester_31ef0033-64e3-4c55-b888-f446541474a6\6.0.9\4.0.8\Pester.psm1'.
Processed: ##vso[task.setprogress value=-1;] 
Loading module from path 'D:\a\_tasks\Pester_31ef0033-64e3-4c55-b888-f446541474a6\6.0.9\4.0.8\lib\Gherkin.dll'.

    namespace Pester
    {
        using System;
        using System.Management.Automation;

        public static class ClosingBraceFinder
        {
            public static int GetClosingBraceIndex(PSToken[] tokens, int startIndex)
            {
                int groupLevel = 1;
                int len = tokens.Length;

                for (int i = startIndex + 1; i < len; i++)
                {
                    PSTokenType type = tokens[i].Type;
                    if (type == PSTokenType.GroupStart)
                    {
                        groupLevel++;
                    }
                    else if (type == PSTokenType.GroupEnd)
                    {
                        groupLevel--;

                        if (groupLevel <= 0) { return i; }
                    }
                }

                return -1;
            }
        }
    }

using System;

namespace Pester
{
    [Flags]
    public enum OutputTypes
    {
        None = 0,
        Default = 1,
        Passed = 2,
        Failed = 4,
        Pending = 8,
        Skipped = 16,
        Inconclusive = 32,
        Describe = 64,
        Context = 128,
        Summary = 256,
        Header = 512,
        All = Default | Passed | Failed | Pending | Skipped | Inconclusive | Describe | Context | Summary | Header,
        Fails = Default | Failed | Pending | Skipped | Inconclusive | Describe | Context | Summary | Header
    }
}
Exporting function 'Context'.
Exporting function 'Describe'.
Exporting function 'In'.
Exporting function 'It'.
Exporting function 'Mock'.
Exporting function 'Assert-VerifiableMock'.
Exporting function 'Assert-MockCalled'.
Exporting function 'Set-TestInconclusive'.
Exporting function 'Assert-VerifiableMocks'.
Exporting function 'InModuleScope'.
Exporting function 'Invoke-Mock'.
Exporting function 'New-Fixture'.
Exporting function 'Get-TestDriveItem'.
Exporting function 'Setup'.
Exporting function 'Should'.
Exporting function 'Invoke-Pester'.
Exporting function 'BeforeEach'.
Exporting function 'AfterEach'.
Exporting function 'BeforeAll'.
Exporting function 'AfterAll'.
Exporting function 'Set-DynamicParameterVariable'.
Exporting function 'Get-MockDynamicParameter'.
Exporting function 'New-PesterOption'.
Exporting function 'SafeGetCommand'.
Exporting function 'Invoke-Gherkin'.
Exporting function 'Find-GherkinStep'.
Exporting function 'Invoke-GherkinStep'.
Exporting function 'BeforeEachFeature'.
Exporting function 'AfterEachFeature'.
Exporting function 'BeforeEachScenario'.
Exporting function 'AfterEachScenario'.
Exporting function 'GherkinStep'.
Exporting alias 'Given'.
Exporting alias 'When'.
Exporting alias 'Then'.
Exporting alias 'And'.
Exporting alias 'But'.
Exporting function 'Add-AssertionOperator'.
Exporting function 'New-MockObject'.
Importing function 'Add-AssertionOperator'.
Importing function 'AfterAll'.
Importing function 'AfterEach'.
Importing function 'AfterEachFeature'.
Importing function 'AfterEachScenario'.
Importing function 'Assert-MockCalled'.
Importing function 'Assert-VerifiableMock'.
Importing function 'Assert-VerifiableMocks'.
Importing function 'BeforeAll'.
Importing function 'BeforeEach'.
Importing function 'BeforeEachFeature'.
Importing function 'BeforeEachScenario'.
Importing function 'Context'.
Importing function 'Describe'.
Importing function 'Find-GherkinStep'.
Importing function 'Get-MockDynamicParameter'.
Importing function 'Get-TestDriveItem'.
Importing function 'GherkinStep'.
Importing function 'In'.
Importing function 'InModuleScope'.
Importing function 'Invoke-Gherkin'.
Importing function 'Invoke-GherkinStep'.
Importing function 'Invoke-Mock'.
Importing function 'Invoke-Pester'.
Importing function 'It'.
Importing function 'Mock'.
Importing function 'New-Fixture'.
Importing function 'New-MockObject'.
Importing function 'New-PesterOption'.
Importing function 'SafeGetCommand'.
Importing function 'Set-DynamicParameterVariable'.
Importing function 'Set-TestInconclusive'.
Importing function 'Setup'.
Importing function 'Should'.
Importing alias 'And'.
Importing alias 'But'.
Importing alias 'Given'.
Importing alias 'Then'.
Importing alias 'When'.
Running Pester from [d:\a\1\s\Tasks\XXXXTWStaging\Tests\] output sent to [d:\a\1\s\Test-Pester.XML]
Exporting function 'EnterTestGroup'.
Exporting function 'LeaveTestGroup'.
Exporting function 'AddTestResult'.
Exporting function 'AddSetupOrTeardownBlock'.
Exporting function 'GetTestCaseSetupBlocks'.
Exporting function 'GetTestCaseTeardownBlocks'.
Exporting function 'GetCurrentTestGroupSetupBlocks'.
Exporting function 'GetCurrentTestGroupTeardownBlocks'.
Exporting function 'EnterTest'.
Exporting function 'LeaveTest'.
Exporting variable 'Strict'.
Exporting variable 'Show'.
Exporting variable 'TagFilter'.
Exporting variable 'ExcludeTagFilter'.
Exporting variable 'TestNameFilter'.
Exporting variable 'SessionState'.
Exporting variable 'CommandCoverage'.
Exporting variable 'InTest'.
Exporting variable 'TestResult'.
Exporting variable 'TotalCount'.
Exporting variable 'Time'.
Exporting variable 'PassedCount'.
Exporting variable 'FailedCount'.
Exporting variable 'SkippedCount'.
Exporting variable 'PendingCount'.
Exporting variable 'InconclusiveCount'.
Exporting variable 'IncludeVSCodeMarker'.
Exporting variable 'TestSuiteName'.
Exporting variable 'TestActions'.
Exporting variable 'TestGroupStack'.
Executing all tests in 'd:\a\1\s\Tasks\XXXXTWStaging\Tests\'




Executing script D:\a\1\s\Tasks\XXXXTWStaging\Tests\L0ValidateDestinationPath.tests.ps1


Importing module: TestHelpersModule
Stubbing command: Import-Module
Setting copyFilesToMachinesPath
Asserting script block should throw: {
   Validate-DestinationPath -value "" -environmentName $validEnvironmentName
}
Success. Matched exception message. Pattern: WFC_ParameterCannotBeNullorEmpty targetPath ; Message: WFC_ParameterCannotBeNullorEmpty targetPath
Asserting script block should throw: {
    Validate-DestinationPath -value $invalidTargetPath -environmentName $validEnvironmentName
}
Success. Matched exception message. Pattern: WFC_RemoteDestinationPathCannotContainEnvironmentVariables $env:abc\123 ; Message: WFC_RemoteDestinationPathCannotContainEnvironmentVariables $env:abc\123


Executing script D:\a\1\s\Tasks\XXXXTWStaging\Tests\L0ValidateSourcePath.tests.ps1


Importing module: TestHelpersModule
Invoking mock command: Import-Module
  Arguments: D:\a\1\s\Tasks\XXXXTWStaging\Tests\lib/TestHelpersModule -Verbose: False
  Command is stubbed.
Stubbing command: Import-Module
Mocking command: Test-Path
  ParametersEvaluator: { $LiteralPath -eq $invalidSourcePath }
  Func: { return $false }
Asserting script block should throw: {
    Validate-SourcePath -value ""
}
Success. Matched exception message. Pattern: WFC_ParameterCannotBeNullorEmpty sourcePath ; Message: WFC_ParameterCannotBeNullorEmpty sourcePath
Asserting script block should throw: {
    Validate-SourcePath -value "$invalidSourcePath"
}
Invoking mock command: Test-Path
  Arguments: -LiteralPath Invalid
  Matching implementation found using parameters evaluator: { $LiteralPath -eq $invalidSourcePath }
  Invoking Func: { return $false }
Success. Matched exception message. Pattern: WFC_SourcePathDoesNotExist Invalid ; Message: WFC_SourcePathDoesNotExist Invalid


Executing script D:\a\1\s\Tasks\XXXXTWStaging\Tests\L0ValidInputSequentialCopy.tests.ps1


Importing module: TestHelpersModule
Invoking mock command: Import-Module
  Arguments: D:\a\1\s\Tasks\XXXXTWStaging\Tests\lib/TestHelpersModule -Verbose: False
  Command is stubbed.
Stubbing command: Import-Module
Setting copyFilesToMachinesPath
Mocking command: Test-Path
  ParametersEvaluator: { $LiteralPath -eq  $validSourcePackage }
  Func: { return $true }
Mocking command: Test-Path
  ParametersEvaluator: { $LiteralPath -eq $invalidSourcePath }
  Func: { return $false }
Mocking command: Invoke-Command
  Func: {  }
Mocking command: ConvertTo-SecureString
  Func: { return $password }
Mocking command: Get-VstsInput
  ParametersEvaluator: { $Name -eq  "SourcePath" }
  Func: { return $validSourcePackage }
Mocking command: Get-VstsInput
  ParametersEvaluator: { $Name -eq  "TargetPath" }
  Func: { return $validApplicationPath }
Mocking command: Get-VstsInput
  ParametersEvaluator: { $Name -eq  "CleanTargetBeforeCopy" }
  Func: { return $true }
Mocking command: Get-VstsInput
  ParametersEvaluator: { $Name -eq "TechWintelDeployService" }
  Func: { return "TechWintelDeployService" }
Mocking command: Get-VstsEndpoint
  ParametersEvaluator: { $Name -eq "TechWintelDeployService" }
  Func: { return $myVar }
Entering D:\a\1\s\Tasks\XXXXTWStaging\WindowsMachineFileCopy.ps1.
Invoking mock command: Get-VstsInput
  Arguments: -Name TechWintelDeployService -Require
  Matching implementation found using parameters evaluator: { $Name -eq "TechWintelDeployService" }
  Invoking Func: { return "TechWintelDeployService" }
Invoking mock command: Get-VstsEndpoint
  Arguments: -Name TechWintelDeployService -Require
  Matching implementation found using parameters evaluator: { $Name -eq "TechWintelDeployService" }
  Invoking Func: { return $myVar }
Invoking mock command: Get-VstsInput
  Arguments: -Name SourcePath -Require
  Matching implementation found using parameters evaluator: { $Name -eq  "SourcePath" }
  Invoking Func: { return $validSourcePackage }
Invoking mock command: Get-VstsInput
  Arguments: -Name TargetPath -Require
  Matching implementation found using parameters evaluator: { $Name -eq  "TargetPath" }
  Invoking Func: { return $validApplicationPath }
Invoking mock command: Get-VstsInput
  Arguments: -Name AdditionalArguments
  Command is stubbed.
Invoking mock command: Get-VstsInput
  Arguments: -Name CleanTargetBeforeCopy
  Matching implementation found using parameters evaluator: { $Name -eq  "CleanTargetBeforeCopy" }
  Invoking Func: { return $true }
Importing VSTSLocStrings
Invoking mock command: Test-Path
  Arguments: -LiteralPath C:\Windows\Test
  Matching implementation found using parameters evaluator: { $LiteralPath -eq  $validSourcePackage }
  Invoking Func: { return $true }
Invoking mock command: ConvertTo-SecureString
  Arguments: Password -AsPlainText -Force
  Invoking Func: { return $password }
Invoking mock command: Invoke-Command
  Arguments: -ScriptBlock 
param (
    [string]$fqdn, 
    [string]$sourcePath,
    [string]$targetPath,
    [object]$credential,
    [string]$cleanTargetBeforeCopy,
    [string]$additionalArguments,
    [string]$scriptRoot
    )

    Import-Module "$scriptRoot\..\ps_modules\VstsTaskSdk" 
    Import-VstsLocStrings -LiteralPath $scriptRoot/Task.json

    Write-Verbose "Entering script RobocopyJob.ps1"
    Write-Verbose "fqdn = $fqdn"
    Write-Verbose "sourcePath = $sourcePath"
    Write-Verbose "targetPath = $targetPath"
    Write-Verbose "credential = $credential"
    Write-Verbose "cleanTargetBeforeCopy = $cleanTargetBeforeCopy"
    Write-Verbose "additionalArguments = $additionalArguments"

    $sourcePath = $sourcePath.Trim().TrimEnd('\', '/')
    $targetPath = $targetPath.Trim().TrimEnd('\', '/')    

    $isFileCopy = Test-Path -Path $sourcePath -PathType Leaf
    $doCleanUp = $cleanTargetBeforeCopy -eq "true"

    $sourceDirectory = $sourcePath
    $filesToCopy = ""
    if($isFileCopy)
    {
        $sourceDirectory = Split-Path $sourcePath
        $filesToCopy = Split-Path $sourcePath -Leaf
    }

    function ThrowError
    {
        param(
            [string]$errorMessage,
            [string]$fqdn
        )

        $failMessage = (Get-VstsLocString -Key "WFC_CopyingFailedForResource" -ArgumentList $fqdn)
        throw "$failMessage`n$errorMessage"
    }

    function Validate-Null(
        [string]$value,
        [string]$variableName
        )
    {
        $value = $value.Trim()    
        if(-not $value)
        {
            ThrowError -errorMessage (Get-VstsLocString -Key "WFC_ParameterCannotBeNullorEmpty" -ArgumentList $variableName)
        }
    }

    function Validate-Credential(
        [object]$credential)
    {
        if($credential)
        {
            Validate-Null $credential.UserName "Username"
            Validate-Null $credential.Password "Password"                        
        }
        else
        {
            ThrowError -errorMessage (Get-VstsLocString -Key "WFC_ParameterCannotBeNullorEmpty" -ArgumentList "credential")
        }   
    }

    function Get-DownLevelLogonName(
        [string]$fqdn,
        [string]$userName
        )
    {
        if($userName  -like '.\*') {
            $userName = $userName.replace(".\","\")
            $userName = $fqdn+$userName
        }
        return $userName
    }

    function Replace-First(
        [string]$text,
        [string]$search, 
        [string]$replace
        )
    {
        $pos = $text.IndexOf($search);
        if ($pos -le 0)
        {
            return $text;
        }

        return $text.Substring(0, $pos) + $replace + $text.Substring($pos + $search.Length);
    }

    function Get-DestinationNetworkPath(
        [string]$targetPath,
        [string]$machineShare
    )
    {
        if(-not $machineShare)
        {
            return $targetPath
        }

        $targetSpecificPath = Replace-First $targetPath ":" '$'    
        return [io.path]::Combine($machineShare, $targetSpecificPath)    
    }    

    function Get-RoboCopyParameters(
        [string]$additionalArguments,
        [switch]$fileCopy,
        [switch]$clean)
    {
        $robocopyParameters = "/COPY:DAT"

        if(-not $fileCopy.IsPresent)
        {
            if($clean.IsPresent)
            {
                $robocopyParameters += " /MIR"
            }
            else
            {
                $robocopyParameters += " /E"
            }
        }       

        if (-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($additionalArguments))
        {
            $robocopyParameters += " $additionalArguments"
        }

        return $robocopyParameters.Trim()
    }

    function Get-MachineShare(
        [string]$fqdn,
        [string]$targetPath
        )
    {
        if([bool]([uri]$targetPath).IsUnc)
        {
            return $targetPath
        }
        if($fqdn)
        {
            return [IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar + [IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar + $fqdn
        }

        return ""
    }

    function Get-NetExeCommand
    {
        $netExePath = Join-Path -path (get-item env:\windir).value -ChildPath system32\net.exe
        if(Test-Path $netExePath)
        {
            Write-Verbose "Found the net exe path $netExePath. Net command will be $netExePath"
            return $netExePath
        }

        Write-Verbose "Unable to get the path for net.exe. Net command will be 'net'"
        return 'net'
    }

    $machineShare = Get-MachineShare -fqdn $fqdn -targetPath $targetPath    
    $destinationNetworkPath = Get-DestinationNetworkPath -targetPath $targetPath -machineShare $machineShare

    Validate-Credential $credential
    $userName = Get-DownLevelLogonName -fqdn $fqdn -userName $($credential.UserName)
    $password = $($credential.Password) 

    $netExeCommand = Get-NetExeCommand

    if($machineShare)
    {
        $command = "$netExeCommand use `"$machineShare`""
        if($userName)
        {
            $command += " /user:`'$userName`' `'$($password -replace "['`]", '$&$&')`'"
        }
        $command += " 2>&1"

        $dtl_mapOut = iex $command
        if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) 
        {
            $errorMessage = (Get-VstsLocString -Key "WFC_FailedToConnectToPathWithUser" -ArgumentList $machineShare, $($credential.UserName)) + $dtl_mapOut
            ThrowError -errorMessage $errorMessage -fqdn $fqdn
        }
    }

    try
    {
        if($isFileCopy -and $doCleanUp -and (Test-Path -path $destinationNetworkPath -pathtype container))
        {
            Get-ChildItem -Path $destinationNetworkPath -Recurse -force | Remove-Item -force -recurse;
            $output = Remove-Item -path $destinationNetworkPath -force -recurse 2>&1
            $err = $output | ?{$_.gettype().Name -eq "ErrorRecord"}
            if($err)
            {
                Write-Verbose -Verbose "Error occurred while deleting the destination folder: $err"
            }
        }

        $robocopyParameters = Get-RoboCopyParameters -additionalArguments $additionalArguments -fileCopy:$isFileCopy -clean:$doCleanUp

        $command = "robocopy `"$sourceDirectory`" `"$destinationNetworkPath`" `"$filesToCopy`" $robocopyParameters"                
        Invoke-Expression $command        

        if ($LASTEXITCODE -ge 8)
        {
            $errorMessage = Get-VstsLocString -Key "WFC_CopyingFailedConsultRobocopyLogsForMoreDetails"            
            ThrowError -errorMessage $errorMessage -fqdn $fqdn            
        }
        else
        {            
            $message = (Get-VstsLocString -Key "WFC_CopyingRecurivelyFrom0to1MachineSucceed" -ArgumentList $sourcePath, $targetPath, $fqdn)
            Write-Output $message            
        }        
    }
    finally
    {
        if($machineShare)
        {            
            $dtl_deleteMap = iex "$netExeCommand use `"$machineShare`" /D /Y";  
        }
    }
 -ArgumentList System.Object[]
  Invoking Func: {  }
Leaving D:\a\1\s\Tasks\XXXXTWStaging\WindowsMachineFileCopy.ps1.
Asserting was-called: Invoke-Command
  Expected times: 1
  Actual times: 1


Executing script D:\a\1\s\Tasks\XXXXTWStaging\Tests\MyFailTest.tests.ps1




  Describing MyFailTest


Invoking mock command: Test-Path
  Arguments: TestDrive:\
  Command is stubbed.
Asserting script block should throw: {
        throw "I do nothing interesting."
    }
    [-] Error occurred in Describe block 
778ms


      RuntimeException: Actual exception message does not match expected pattern. Expected: Not that message because I want a failure ; Actual: I do nothing interesting.


      at Assert-Throws, D:\a\1\s\Tasks\XXXXTWStaging\Tests\lib\TestHelpersModule\PublicFunctions.ps1: line 67


      at <ScriptBlock>, D:\a\1\s\Tasks\XXXXTWStaging\Tests\MyFailTest.tests.ps1: line 5


      at DescribeImpl, D:\a\_tasks\Pester_31ef0033-64e3-4c55-b888-f446541474a6\6.0.9\4.0.8\Functions\Describe.ps1: line 161




  Describing MyPassTest


Invoking mock command: Test-Path
  Arguments: TestDrive:\
  Command is stubbed.
Asserting script block should throw: {
        throw "I will pass"
    }
Success. Matched exception message. Pattern: I will pass ; Message: I will pass
Tests completed in 778ms


Tests Passed: 0, 
Failed: 1, 
Skipped: 0, 
Pending: 0, 
Inconclusive: 0 


Perform operation 'Enumerate CimInstances' with following parameters, ''namespaceName' = root\cimv2,'className' = Win32_OperatingSystem'.
Operation 'Enumerate CimInstances' complete.
##[error]Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException: Pester returned errors
Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException: Pester returned errors
##[error]PowerShell script completed with 1 errors.
##[section]Finishing: Pester Test Runner


Evaluating condition for step: 'Publish Test Results Test-Pester.XML'
Evaluating: succeededOrFailed()
Evaluating succeededOrFailed:
=> (Boolean) True
Expanded: True
Result: True
##[section]Starting: Publish Test Results Test-Pester.XML
==============================================================================
Task         : Publish Test Results
Description  : Publish Test Results to VSTS/TFS
Version      : 2.0.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613742)
==============================================================================
agent.workFolder=d:\a
loading inputs and endpoints
loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
loading INPUT_MERGETESTRESULTS
loading INPUT_PUBLISHRUNATTACHMENTS
loading INPUT_SEARCHFOLDER
loading INPUT_TESTRESULTSFILES
loading INPUT_TESTRUNNER
loaded 8
testRunner=NUnit
testResultsFiles=Test-Pester.XML
mergeTestResults=true
platform=null
configuration=null
testRunTitle=null
publishRunAttachments=true
searchFolder=d:\a\1\s
testRunner: NUnit
testResultsFiles: Test-Pester.XML
mergeResults: true
platform: null
config: null
testRunTitle: null
publishRunAttachments: true
defaultRoot: 'd:\a\1\s'
findOptions.followSpecifiedSymbolicLink: 'true'
findOptions.followSymbolicLinks: 'true'
matchOptions.debug: 'false'
matchOptions.nobrace: 'true'
matchOptions.noglobstar: 'false'
matchOptions.dot: 'true'
matchOptions.noext: 'false'
matchOptions.nocase: 'true'
matchOptions.nonull: 'false'
matchOptions.matchBase: 'false'
matchOptions.nocomment: 'false'
matchOptions.nonegate: 'false'
matchOptions.flipNegate: 'false'
pattern: 'Test-Pester.XML'
findPath: 'd:\a\1\s\Test-Pester.XML'
statOnly: 'true'
found 1 paths
applying include pattern
adjustedPattern: 'd:\a\1\s\Test-Pester.XML'
1 matches
1 final results
Reading test results from file 'd:\a\1\s\Test-Pester.XML'
Processed: ##vso[results.publish type=NUnit;mergeResults=true;publishRunAttachments=true;resultFiles=d:\a\1\s\Test-Pester.XML;]
task result: Succeeded
Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Succeeded;]
##[section]Async Command Start: Publish test results
Publishing test results to test run '17948'
Test results remaining: 1. Test run id: 17948
Published Test Run : https://XXXX.visualstudio.com/DevOps/_TestManagement/Runs#runId=17948&_a=runCharts
##[section]Async Command End: Publish test results
##[section]Finishing: Publish Test Results Test-Pester.XML
```

Comment: Can you show the whole logs by setting system.debug as true in VSTS? And does the helloworld is the full script of the .test.ps1 file, if not, can you show the entire script in .test.ps1 file?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT I added as much logging as the 30k char limit would allow. I also included the full script. All that was missing in my original post was the cmdlet binding and param lines at the top.

Comment: But based on the pester test runner log, the test result is 1 passed and 1 failed. So the test result will only show 1 failed test. And it block is truly should under describe block, and you can find it in all the tests.ps1 examples as https://github.com/pester/Pester/wiki/Pester and http://wahlnetwork.com/2016/11/28/building-powershell-unit-tests-pester-using-mock-commands/.

Answer (score 0):

At the suggestion of a coworker I tried adding "**It"** blocks around my tests. That seemed to work. I won't mark this as the answer yet as I didn't see it blocks in the example I was working off of. My code now looks like:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param()

Describe MyFailTest{
    It "This will fail, the patterns don't match"{
        Assert-Throws {
            throw "I do nothing interesting."
        } -MessagePattern "Not that message because I want a failure"
    }
}


Describe MyPassTest{
    It "This will pass, the patterns do match"{
        Assert-Throws {
            throw "I will pass"
        } -MessagePattern "I will pass"
    }
}
```